# Object destructuring with default parameters in Node.js 8.9.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, destructuring, default-parameters

I had a problem running this piece of code here when it was saved to a text file and ran with node in the command line.

```
let x;

{k1: x = null } = {k1: "Hello"};
console.log(x);
```

Running this would throw an error at the assignment operator being invalid.

However, when the code is directly input into the node interpreter, it'll print out `"Hello"` which is what I'm expecting.

Anyone know what this could be? The idea is to construct a class with default values and update the class using the same method, reusing the current values when something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [assignment wihout declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

```
let x;
({k1: x = null } = {k1: "Hello"});
```

or just:

```
let { k1: x = null } = { k1: "Hello" };
```

> The round braces ( ... ) around the assignment statement is required
> syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a
> declaration.
>
> {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2} is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b}
> on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}) is valid, as is var {a, b} = {a: 1,
> b: 2}
>
> NOTE: Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or
> it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.